# Chromecast Chrome Sender - Detect Media Playback Finished

Tags: javascript, chromecast

I can't seem to find a  Chromecast receiver event that signals that a video playback has been completed on the receiver app.

My goal is to close the cast session after the casted video has ended.

I know that in the receiver app I can listen to the ended event on the receiver player and then send a message via custom namespace to the sender, but thats a workaround and I would rather avoid doing that.

From the docs I had a sense that this should work:

```
this.remotePlayerController.addEventListener(
            window.cast.framework.RemotePlayerEventType.MEDIA_INFO_CHANGED,
            () => {
                const session = this.getSession();

                if (session) {
                    const mediaStatus = session.getMediaSession() || {};

                    switch (mediaStatus.idleReason) {
                    case window.chrome.cast.media.IdleReason.FINISHED:
                       // Code to close session here


                    }
                }
            }
        );
```

but it doesn't, because for some reason mediaStatus.idleReason does not evaluate, but it does exist because when console loging just mediaStatus i can see that it has the idleReason and it is set to "FINISHED"?!
and there are no obvious methods in the mediaStatus object that returns its idleReason property...